# Como criar um URI Scheme

Tags: windows

Como se cria um `URI Scheme` para abrir um programa.
`URI Scheme` é o que o *Torrent*, *Skype*, *TeamSpeak*, *Discord* entre outros programas usam para abrir o próprio programa pela `WEB`.

***Exemplo:*** `ts3server://servidor.com.br:4000`

Answer (score 2):

Voce precisa registrar  o seu URI Scheme no registro do windows segue o caminho do registro:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/
  your-protocol-name/
    (Default)    "URL:your-protocol-name Protocol"
    URL Protocol ""
    shell/
      open/
        command/
          (Default) PathToExecutable
```

Exemplo prático:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/
   alert/
      (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
      shell/
         open/
            command/
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"
```

Mais detalhes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx